# How to use System calls of an OS?

Tags: operating-system

I have a big confusion regarding the system calls in OS. According to the book "operating systems concepts 9th ", it is mentioned (in page 63) that :

> Most programmers never see this level of detail, however. Typically,
> application developers design programs according to an application
> programming interface (API).
>
> Behind the scenes, the functions that make up an API typically invoke
> the actual system calls on behalf of the application programmer.

This means that we as programmers don't use the system calls directly. However, I see videos that teach how to use system calls directly, like this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAUjjS0gxxg) , where it access the read|() and write() system calls. I am confused, please someone explain if the system calls can be used directly or using APIs or using both ??

Answer (score 0):

Typically, system calls are invoked using some assembly. The C/C++ calls that must invoke system calls (like read() or write()) are compiled to assembly then to binary. The assembly to invoke a system call is really simple. It is some `mov` instructions to put the arguments in some conventional registers (specified in the ABI of the OS) then the actual `syscall` instruction.

The `syscall` instruction makes x86-64 processors jump at the address specified in the STAR64 MSR register. For example, Linux places the address of the first instruction of the file entry_64.s in STAR64.

The read() and write() calls are C/C++ calls in the OS API. They are often named system calls because the API is really just a thin wrapper which makes system calls directly.